# Using PHP to read Wordpress Posts

Tags: custom-field

I'm a beginner in PHP and Wordpress and I would appreciate help on project I'm working on.

Currently I am using the below code to query a specific post and then echo it's expiration date (expiration date is set through a plugin) in a wordpress site:

```
<?php 
   $postid = 3823;
   $date_format = __( 'd / m / Y' );
   $expiration_date = get_post_meta( $postid, '_expiration_date', true);
   echo date_i18n( $date_format, strtotime( $expiration_date ) ); 
?>
```

This is working fine. What I would like it to do is:

- I will have 2 posts, 1 published and one scheduled
- Query both posts, check which is publiched and echo it's expiration date

Comment: Could you add "the below code"? :)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Just a tip, when adding code, highlight it and click on the `{}` sign above the editor. This will add your code in a code block that will make your code more readable :-). To learn how the site operates, feel free to take a [tour] and visit [ask] and [help] to learn how to ask good questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the function [get_post_status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) 
Example:

```
if (get_post_status($postid)=='publish')
echo date_i18n( $date_format, strtotime( $expiration_date ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The function you supplied did the trick but i think my code is taking the long way. I am using the above code - including your IF statement - twice, one for each post number. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Yes. Ideally you would use the loop (http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)  to read through your posts. You could also use query_post to apply a specific category to your two posts and read only the posts using that category (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Scroll down that first link for an example checking the category.